# Routing via Php AltoRouter

Tags: php, routes, router, altorouter

I am trying to use a router (AltoRouter) for the first time and am unable to call any page.

Web folder structure

[image]
The Code

Index.php

```
require 'lib/AltoRouter.php';

$router = new AltoRouter();
$router->setBasePath('/alto');
$router->map('GET|POST','/', 'home#index', 'home');
$router->map('GET|POST','/', 'display.php', 'display');
$router->map('GET','/plan/', 'plan.php', 'plan');
$router->map('GET','/users/', array('c' => 'UserController', 'a' => 'ListAction'));
$router->map('GET','/users/[i:id]', 'users#show', 'users_show');
$router->map('POST','/users/[i:id]/[delete|update:action]', 'usersController#doAction', 'users_do');
// match current request
$match = $router->match();

if( $match && is_callable( $match['target'] ) ) {
    call_user_func_array( $match['target'], $match['params'] ); 
} else {
    // no route was matched
    header( $_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"] . ' 404 Not Found');
}
```

I have a file named plan.php (display plan) in the plan folder and the hyperlink that I am trying is

```
<a href="<?php echo $router->generate('plan'); ?>">Plan <?php echo $router->generate('plan'); ?></a>
```

which does not work.

Can you help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot call plan.php by passing `plan.php` as an argument to `match` function

Check examples at http://altorouter.com/usage/processing-requests.html

If you want to use content from plan.php

you should use `map` in the following format

```
$router->map('GET','/plan/',  function() {
    require __DIR__ . '/plan/plan.php';
} , 'plan');
```

to the file `plan/plan.php` add `echo 'testing plan';`

Also, double check that your .htaccess file contains

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Also, if you set base path with `$router->setBasePath('/alto');` your `index.php` files should be placed in the `alto` directory so your url would be in that case `http://example.com/alto/index.php`

Working example:

```
require 'lib/AltoRouter.php';

$router = new AltoRouter();
$router->setBasePath('/alto');

$router->map('GET','/plan/',  function(  ) {
    require __DIR__ . '/plan/plan.php';
} , 'plan');

// match current request
$match = $router->match();

if( $match && is_callable( $match['target'] ) ) {
    call_user_func_array( $match['target'], $match['params'] ); 
} else {
    // no route was matched
    header( $_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"] . ' 404 Not Found');
}
```

then this will work just fine

```
<a href="<?php echo $router->generate('plan'); ?>">Plan <?php echo $router->generate('plan'); ?></a>
```

Comment: I got the home page working but am unable to call plan.php. The home page has a link to plan <a href="#">Plan</a> which I changed to <a href="<?php echo $router->generate('plan'); ?>">Plan <?php echo $router->generate('plan'); ?></a>.

Comment: home#index this works because most likely you have class Home with method index in it. 

 $router->map('GET','/plan/',  function(  ) {
    require __DIR__ . '/plan/plan.php';
} , 'plan'); 

When the route is matched this function above includes plan.php file. Alternative you may create class `plan` with method index and then you will be able to pass plan#index in the same way as for home page.