# PHP route with Using AltoRouter Library

Tags: php, altorouter

I need help. I am currently trying to use PHP route AltoRouter but it does not work for me. Here is my code:

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$router = new AltoRouter();

$router->map('GET', '/', function(){

    echo 'It is working';
});

$match = $router->match();

// Here comes the new part, taken straight from the docs:

// call closure or throw 404 status
if( $match && is_callable( $match['target'] ) ) {
   
   call_user_func_array( $match['target'], $match['params'] );

} else {

   // no route was matched
   header( $_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"] . ' 404 Not Found');

}
```

**My browser output:**
[image: My browser output]

The existing list of answers I found are still not working for my code. I need help please. It's totally messing with my head.
THANK YOU VERY MUCH!

The current answers I found that did not solve for me:

[PHP AltoRouter - can't get GET request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28152847/php-altorouter-cant-get-get-request/63520487#63520487) 
[Routing via Php AltoRouter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38149885/routing-via-php-altorouter)

Comment: What error did you get when you tried the answers you linked to?

Comment: Thank you very much maybe I am prostrated and tired last time I review the link, I got it thanks again to help and solving my problem. @segFault